# merging jquery mousenter / mouseleave animations

Tags: jquery, function

I imagine this is pretty simple for someone in the know - but I can't figure it out.

How would i simplify these two mousenter / mouseleave animations into one piece of code?

```
$("#newsitem").mouseenter(function(){
$("#newsitem").stop().animate({ width: "300px", opacity: "1"     }, 300 ); 
});

$("#newsitem").mouseleave(function(){
$("#newsitem").stop().animate({  width: "204px", opacity: "0.5"   }, 300 ); 
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer below helped you, please be sure to mark it as the answer to your question!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#newsitem").bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var dynamicWidth = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 300 : 204;
    var dynamicOpacity = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1 : 0.5;
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: dynamicWidth, opacity: dynamicOpacity }, 300); 
});
```

I wrote it like this simply to explicitly encompass your scenario here.  If you simply want to have a hover function, you can do that too.

Comment: interesting - I'll give this a try

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
$("#newsitem").hover(function(){
    //mousein events
},function(){
    //mouseout events    
});
```

Comment: definitely favor hover over the enter/leave suggestions.

Comment: I can't rememeber why - but when I first used this there was a reason why I didn;t use hover - I'll try and check it out...

Comment: just to say that this is what I actually used - but I marked above as corrent as it is technically the correct answer to my question - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#newsitem").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).stop().animate({ width: "300px", opacity: "1" }, 300 ); }).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).stop().animate({  width: "204px", opacity: "0.5" }, 300 ); });
```

?

Comment: This is chaining not concatenation... (you'll have to define "one piece of code" better then :)

Comment: It wasnt a criticism, just not what was asked in the question.

Comment: What was it then, for a comment to add value it must show me what was wrong or show the question its true meaning. I've seen neither of this in it.

Comment: The question title was : 'merging jquery mousenter / mouseleave animations'. Personally I would take that to be not just chaining but to have it such as Adam Terlson's answer.

Comment: You're right, my brain remembered the body of the question better than the title.

Comment: This is actually really useful for me to know actually, as I'm not up on chaining, but I think the above answer is more of a merge. Definitely a valuable contribution for me though